# Exception in Task

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, task

I have to two Tasks inside a function and each has Try Catch to handle the exceptions.
But i want to know what will happen, if i return from the function when there is exception in the first task and the second also ends up with Exception.
Will the Second Task's exception goes unhandled and crash the application when the Finalize is called on that Task object by GC.

Sample Code:

```
public void ProcessJob()
    {
        var Job1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Dojob1());
        var Job2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Dojob2());

        try
        {
            Job1.Wait();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
          //Handle Exception
          return;
        }

        //some other actions.


       try
       {
          Job2.Wait();
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {
          //Handle Exception
          return;
       }
    }
```

Comment: If you synchronously wait for the tasks to complete anyway, why use tasks in the first place?  Why not just directly call `Dojob1()` and `Dojob2()`?  Generally for handling errors you can add continuations to tasks and examine the state of the tasks (including any thrown exceptions) within those continuations.  That's for an asynchronous setup, which you're not really using.

Comment: unhandled exception in a Task no longer tear down the app (since .Net 4.5)

Comment: @David. Thanks of the reply. The above code is just a outline of the original problem. I am wanted to know the result of the above code.

Comment: @I3arnon Thanks for point. But i was using 4.

Answer (score 2):

If you leave the function before observing the potential exception of Job2 this will invoke the TPL unhandled error behavior you mentioned. Why wouldn't it? The structure that your code has is unknown to the TPL. The TPL cannot magically change its behavior in response to how you write your methods.

Starting with .NET 4.5 unhandled exceptions no longer crash the process. Still, do not ignore them. Exceptions can indicate bugs.

Maybe you can simplify your code by using `Parallel.Invoke` or `Task.WaitAll`. Of course, this delays the return of the method until all tasks have completed even in case Job1 fails.

There is a way to ignore the exception caused by Job2 but ignoring errors is not a good option. At the very least they should be logged.